# Add Visualforce Page as a window in Service Cloud Console

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

I'm trying to add a visual force page, that starts a flow, in the service cloud console and it's not working. I go into `Customize` --> `Cases` --> `Page Layout` 
but there is no option there to add a `Visualforce Page`.

Anyone know how to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you want to add a vf page as a window. For this go to edit page layout and on top of the options far right to save, cancel options, you will find, Custom console components.

Open this and choose from the list of options.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I can try to help you here but I need more info.

When you say "add Visualforce page as a window" what do you mean exactly? Do you want to add a Visualforce page as a sidebar component of a tab or do you simply want to overwrite a detail page with a Visualforce page?

Answer (score 0):

Select the object, go to page layout -> Select the layout which you want to edit -> On the top click Custom Console Components.. Choose the place where you want to show the window and select the visualforce page